# Websockets: listen multiple connections simultaneously?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, websocket

I am working on a project which goal is to receive and store real time data from financial exchanges, using websockets. I have some very general questions about the technology.

Suppose that I have two websocket connections open, receiving real time data from two different servers. How do I make sure not to miss any messages? I have learned a bit of asynchronous programming (python asyncio) but it does not seem to solve the problem: when I listen to one connection, I cannot listen to the other one at the same time, right?

I can think of two solutions: the first one would require that the servers use a buffer system to send their data, but I do not think this is the case (Binance, Bitfinex...). The second solution I see is to listen each websocket using a different core. If my laptop has 8 cores I can listen to 8 connections and be sure not to miss any messages. I guess I can then scale up by using a cloud service.

Is that correct or am I missing something? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> when I listen to one connection, I cannot listen to the other one at the same time, right?

Wrong.

When using an evented programming design, you will be using an IO "reactor" that adds IO related events to the event loop.

This allows your code to react to events from a number of connections.

It's true that the code reacts to the events in sequence, but as long as your code doesn't "block", these events could be handled swiftly and efficiently.

Blocking code should be avoided and big / complicated tasks should be fragmented into a number of "events". There should be no point at which your code is "blocking" (waiting) on an IO `read` or `write`.

This will allow your code to handle all the connections without significant delays.

> ...the first one would require that the servers use a buffer system to send their data...

Many evented frameworks use an internal buffer that streams to the IO when "ready" events are raised. For example, look up the `drained` event in node.js (or the `on_ready` in facil.io).

This is a convenience feature rather than a requirement.

The event loop might as well add an "on ready" event and assume your code will handle buffering after partial `write` calls return `EAGAIN` / `EWOULDBLOCK`.

> The second solution I see is to listen each websocket using a different core.

No need. A single thread on a single core with an evented design should support thousands (and tens of thousands) of concurrent clients with reasonable loads (per-client load is a significant performance factor).

Attaching TCP/IP connections to a specific core can (sometimes) improve performance, but this is a many-to-one relationship. If we had to dedicate a CPU core per connection than server prices would shoot through the roof.

Comment: upvoted! I have the same question with a few more addons ...is there a limit on how many exchanges a thread can handle? how do we find out if messages are being dropped ? if you had to add 200 exchanges like coinmarketcap, would you create more processes where each process handles say N exchanges? what would be a reasonable way to store the data and forward it to clients? redis? kafka? zmq ? a newbie here so some direction is super appreciated